# excel sumifs how to convert a range value from a day into a date so that the criteria can test if the date falls between two dates

Tags: excel, date, range, criteria, sumifs

I have a day field denoting which day of a month a debit comes out of an account. These are listed by start date end date and day number of withdrawal and value.

On a separate sheet I have a running fortnightly income and expenditure sheet and I want to include those fixed regular costs on the right fortnightly value. 
I currently use the following sumifs statement:

```
=(SUMIFS(Fixed!$F:$F,Fixed!$C:$C,"Monthly",Fixed!$D:$D,">"&DAY('monthly forecast 2017'!H1),Fixed!$D:$D,"<"&DAY('monthly forecast 2017'!I1),Fixed!$B:$B,">"&H1,Fixed!$A:$A,"<"&'monthly forecast 2017'!I1))
```

The worksheet `Fixed!` is the sheet containing the fixed regular costs.

`Fixed!$F:$F` - the data being calculated in the sumifs
criteria range 1: `Fixed!$C:$C` -  include if row value is "monthly"

criteria range 2: `Fixed!$D:$D,">"&DAY('monthly forecast 2017'!H1)` - include if day number `$D` which is greater than the day number of the 'from' date of the fortnight column e.g. fortnight from H1 = 01-01-17  to H2 = 14-01-17

criteria range 3: `Fixed!$D:$D,"<"&DAY('monthly forecast 2017'!I1)` as above but if day number `$D` is less than the start of the next fortnight e.g. fortnight from I1 = 01-01-17  to I2 = 14-01-17

criteria range 4 & 5: just ensures the start and end date of this repeating bill does not after or before the fortnight respectively.

The problem is that where a fortnight is in 1 month and ends in another e.g. from column F the dates from 26-02-17 to 11-03-17 will fail to work as intended  when a bill falls on the 27th. As the criteria of range 3 fails to capture 2 different months. Therefore I tried to convert the day value to a date value based on the month in question e.g.

Criteria 2 becomes: `DATE(year(F1),month(F1),day(Fixed!$D:$D),">"&'monthly forecast 2017'!F1` where F1 = start date of the forthnight. However this will not work due to improper use of the `DATE()` function on a range.

I need to either be able to convert a day to a specific date in order to check if the fixed bills falls between the two dates or I need to change the formula. I feel that latter but at the moment I cannot think of another method other than creating a VB script.

[Example of fixed costs sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieucW.jpg)

[Example of calculated fortnightly costs (income/expenditure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOaiN.jpg)

As you can see the first value should be in a column where the 27th day is in that fortnight. But it is not included when the fortnight ends in the next month.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking your problem.

If the data in fixed is in date format (i.e. 01/02/2017 for example), excel sees it as a number. which means you can compare dates without any other calculation :
this will then be your formula (for one criteria, I'll let you put in the others):

```
sumif(fixed!$D1:$D10,"<"&'monthly forecast 2017'!I1)
```

For the fornight part, you then add the number of days to your criteria.

I may not have fully understood your problem, feel free to comment to help me get it.

Comment: I don't think that would work. the date value is a recurring value that occurs every month. I could create a whole column of all date values for that and that could be used in the range but then i have to keep generating every date possibility, e.g. 27/01/17, 27/02/17, 27/03/17, 27/04/17 until the bill ends. if i have it in a full date 27/01/2017 that would work for the first month but will not be included in the fortnights where the 27th occurs in other months i.e. 27/02/17

Comment: I do not understand your problem it seems...
I think I do not exactly understand what you are trying to do. Could you please try to say it otherwise with another example ?
I am trying to think  of a way to get rid of the month/year.
Plus if an event starts january the 30th what would you want to see on february ?

Comment: I have added to images to give you an indication of the page structures. As you can see the first value should be in a column where the 27th day is in that fortnight. But it is not included when the fortnight ends in the next month.

Comment: I cannot view them from work, I'll give it a look as soon as I am home.